# delete ';' at the end of each line

Tags: linux, unix, sed

I have a huge (10+ GB) .csv file on a Linux server. The lines look somehow like this:

```
6;20000327;20000425;990099,0;20000327;LL;UBXO;7;-1;62;F;30;001;NO;NO;wgB;0;99;0002;5530;001;708;196;1;AA;N;N;100;53,81;0;0;0;1;1;;1;
6;20000327;20000425;990099,0;20000425;LL;OLD*;62;62;92;F;30;001;NO;NO;ueB;0;99;0002;XXXX;001;;;1;AA;N;N;;;0;0;1;0;0;;30;
```

I am searching for a fast script to do the following:

1. change any occurrence of `<number>,<number>` to `<number>.<number>`
2. delete the last semicolon of each line

I have especially problems with the second one, because the script shouldn't mind if it is a Linux file or a windows file.

I tried to do it with sed but failed thus far.

[edit]

I finally used a mix of Dennis Williams and SiegeX solutions:

```
sed 's/;\([0-9]*\),\([0-9]*\);/;\1.\2;/g;s/;\(\r\?\)$/\1/' inputfile
```

(the part with s/;[[:blank:]]*$// didn't work at my file...)

Comment: sorry, for not marking this thread as solved for such a long time - suddenly my internet connection at work broke down. thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed 's/;\([0-9]*\),\([0-9]*\);/;\1.\2;/g;s/;[[:blank:]]*$//' ./infile
```

Comment: the [[:blank:]] part didn't work for me - however it worked with a combination of yours and Dennis Williamsons solution. Thank you!

Comment: @Marcel: hmm, that is quite odd.  What if you replaced `[[:blank:]]` in my script with a simple space as in `s/; *$//`, does it work then?

Comment: doesn't work either, I'm afraid. Maybe this output heps you?
``# cat -A filename.csv 
6;20000327;20000425;990099,0;20000327;LL;UBXO;7;-1;62;F;30;001;NO;NO;wgB;0;99;0002;5530;001;708;196;1;AA;N;N;100;53,81;0;0;0;1;1;;1;^M$``
``6;20000327;20000425;990099,0;20000425;LL;OLD*;62;62;92;F;30;001;NO;NO;ueB;0;99;0002;XXXX;001;;;1;AA;N;N;;;0;0;1;0;0;;30;^M$``

Comment: @Marcel I see, well it looks like Dennis had some foresight that your csv file would be terminated with the DOS-style `\r\n` rather than the unix style of simple `\n`.  What if you now replace [[:blank:]] with [[:space:]] as in `s/;[[:space:]]*$//`

Comment: I think Dennis wouldn't rely on foresight but on the sentence: "... because the script shouldn't mind if it is a Linux file or a windows file." in my question ;-)

[[:space:]] works! thank you!

Comment: @Marcel aha, missed that part

Answer (score 3):

```
$ cat file
6;20000327;20000425;990099,0;20000327;LL;UBXO;7;-1;62;F;30;001;NO;NO;wgB;0;99;0002;5530;001;708;196;1;AA;N;N;100;53,81;0;0;0;1;1;;1;
6;20000327;20000425;990099,0;20000425;LL;OLD*;62;62;92;F;30;001;NO;NO;ueB;0;99;0002;XXXX;001;;;1;AA;N;N;;;0;0;1;0;0;;30;

$ perl -p -e 's/(\d+),(\d+)/\1.\2/g; s/;$//' file
6;20000327;20000425;990099.0;20000327;LL;UBXO;7;-1;62;F;30;001;NO;NO;wgB;0;99;0002;5530;001;708;196;1;AA;N;N;100;53.81;0;0;0;1;1;;1
6;20000327;20000425;990099.0;20000425;LL;OLD*;62;62;92;F;30;001;NO;NO;ueB;0;99;0002;XXXX;001;;;1;AA;N;N;;;0;0;1;0;0;;30
```

Note: perl handles different line endings for you.

Comment: +1 because I didn't realize you could do two expressions on one line, thanks maxim!

Comment: `s/;$//'` would be shorter and accomplish the same thing for the removal of the last semi-colon.  Although you might want to allow for some form of blanks between the semi-colon and EOL.  See my answer for basically the same thing in sed but without the niceity of being able to use `\d`

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try:

```
sed 's/,/./g;s/;\r\?$//' inputfile
```

To preserve the carriage return if it's there:

```
sed 's/,/./g;s/;\(\r\?\)$/\1/' inputfile
```

Comment: I worry that a blanket replacement of commas to periods may have undesirable side affects only because the OP specifically said the comma must be surrounded by numbers. Granted his sample input only showed that as the case.

Comment: Use "sed -i" to change the file in place.

Comment: don't know if it's save to "ignore" the numbers before the commas. Better to be on the save side...

Comment: thank you, once more! I would like to accept your solution AND SiegeXs solution, as you both were responsible for the script to work. I will accept SiegeXs solution simply because you have more points anyway!

Answer (score 1):

If you are handy with perl, you You can use a [perl one liner](http://blog.ksplice.com/2010/05/top-10-perl-one-liner-tricks/) to do these things. Here's an example of you might do the number change:

```
 perl -i -pe 's/(\d),(\d)/$1\.$2/' yourfile
```

be very careful with the -i option, as it causes perl to operate on the existing file in place.

Comment: don't know if I have perl on the server - but even if - I think sed will be faster, right (on 10GB speed matters ...)

Comment: marcel, sed will not necessarily be faster unless you also use in place with -i: http://www.philchen.com/2007/05/28/string-substitution-in-perl-vs-sed-removing-disk-io-factor