# change last two digits of a number using sed

Tags: regex, linux, date, sed

I use this command:

```
sed 's/;\([0-9]*\),\([0-9]*\);/;\1.\2;/g;s/;\(\r\?\)$/\1/' inputfile
```

to change huge csv-files to my needs (see [delete ';' at the end of each line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5184031/delete-at-the-end-of-each-line)).

Now it happens that in some csv-files there are "fictive dates" like 20000500 that can't be imported to SQL because of the last two zeros (that are not possible for dates).

How can I edit my sed-command to always change the last two digits to 01 in such cases (I mean only if they are 00)?

I tried

```
sed 's/;\([0-9]*\),\([0-9]*\);/;\1.\2;/g;s/;\([0-9]{6}\)00;/;\101;/g;s/;\(\r\?\)$/\1/' inputfile
```

but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think `{6}` is an extended regular expression. So you either have to use `sed -r` or you change your regexp to `s/;\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\)00;/;\101;/g`.

If you want to use extended regular expressions, do:

```
sed -r 's/;([0-9]{6})00;/;\101;/g'
```

I.e.: you have to remove the backslashes from parens.

Edit: Regarding to Dennis Williamson's comment it's also possible to use regular regexps by escaping the curly braces:

```
sed 's/;\([0-9]\{6\}\)00;/;\101;/g'
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could escape the curly braces.

Comment: Thank you Dennis, that's a good point. I will also add this to my answer.